# Provide output of C program as command line input Java program?

Tags: command-line, pipe

I was learning about Unix file system and learned about **pipes**. According to [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operating-system-unix-file-system/),

> A pipe holds the output of the first command till it has been read by the second program

So, I was thinking if I could **link** a **C program** and a **Java Program** so as to supply the output of the C code as the command line arguments for the Java code.

Here are my codes:

**c.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("World");
    return 0;
}
```

**Java.java**

```
public class Java{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        System.out.println("Hello "+a[0]); 
    }
}
```

I tried to link the C object file execution command and the Java class execution command so that the output turns out to be:

```
Hello World
```

This is what I tried:

```
gcc -o c c.c
javac Java.java

./c | java Java
```

It didn't go as I expected. The Java program didn't receive the output of the C program and simply threw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. Also, I didn't see the output of the C program.

**How can I achieve my goal, if at all this is possible?**

Comment: You’ve swapped “arguments” for “input”....

Comment: @reviewers: This question is about pipes and command line arguments handling, not about programming...

Comment: Been a long time since I've done C/C++ programming, but aren't you trying to access an argument to your `./c` program that you didn't provide (in your example at least)?  First make sure each program works as expected individually - THEN tie them together with a pipe (or `xargs` or i/o redirection or ....)

Comment: @ivanivan The C and Java programs work perfectly individually. The `./c` command executes the C object file and shows `World` as the output.

Comment: You need to use stdin in Java not arguments. if you don't know how to do it I think your question belong to stack overflow here's probably your answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/13095983/1195001

Comment: Progyammer - and the java program will output something if you do `java Java turtle` ?

Comment: @ivanivan Yes. It would output `Hello turtle!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is possible and easy. 
Just type

```
/your/java/program "$(/your/c/program)"
```

The `$(…)` notation is called “command substitution”. 
`$(command1)`
runs `command1` with output to a pipe,
captures it, and puts it on the command line. 
So

```
command2 $(command1)
```

runs `command2`
with `command1`’s output
as a command-line argument. 
You should add quotes (`"…"`) to handle the case
where the output from `command1`
(i.e., your C program) is multiple words (e.g., `printf("planet earth");`). 
This is what you are asking for.

I discuss this in some length [here](https://superuser.com/q/935374/354511#935427), where I show the example

```
$ ls -ld "$(date "+%B %Y").txt"
-rwxr-xr-x  1 username groupname    687 Apr  2 11:09 April 2018.txt
```

P.S. If you are on a very old or unusual system,
the `$(…)` notation might not work. 
In that case, try

```
/your/java/program "`/your/c/program`"
```

`` `…` `` is an old version of `$(…)`. 
If `$(…)` works on your system, use it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is possible but not as easily as you tried. As you correctly stated a pipeline provides input, not command line arguments.

Luckily there is a (standard) program which does just that: `xargs`

In the GNU world (Linux) the best way would be to separate the output elements with literal zero bytes:

```
/your/c/program | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 /your/java/program
```

You can easily try this with `echo` (which is the default command for `xargs` anyway`:

```
echo '/bin
/etc
/usr' | xargs ls -ld
```

Comment: Wow! It worked like a charm.
So basically, `xargs` feasibly _converts_ the output of command 1 as arguments to be provided to command 2. Is that correct?

Comment: @progyammer Yes, in general. This can be configured in several ways. You should have a look at `man xargs` to get an impression of the important options.